# Function doesn´t fire in separated function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some troubles with jquery.
If i provide my Jquery in a function it doesn´t fire..

```
function foo(){
        $(this).hide();
 }   
<input type='button' value='Button' onclick='foo()'>
```

I have tried to fire the event inside onclick and it worked.

```
<input type='button' value='Button' onclick='$(this).hide()'>
```

I think the problem is the 'this' object, but i couldn´t figure out why.

Comment: Works fine http://jsfiddle.net/y9Lvpoab/

Comment: inside the the onclick it worked quite well.

Comment: see my answer and let me know it helped you are not and if you have any query let me know my friend :D

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
function foo(obj){
        $(obj).hide();
 }   
<input type='button' value='Button' onclick='foo(this)'>
```

Comment: i stell get the error: Uncaught TypeError: obj.hide is not a function

Comment: use `$(obj)` because `.hide`  is a **`jquery`** method

Comment: Thanks $(obj) helpt me out!

Answer (score 1):

I'll asume that the function lays on it's script tag which is in the end of the body (Good assumption ?), then try this `function foo(e){$(e.target).hide()}` or use vanilla JS because It is simple even without jQuery (Optimize) :D

Comment: i use an extanal script file to store all my functions. (Just an expamle of my code)

Answer (score 1):

`hide()` is a jquery function and you have to run it on a jquery object.
Why don't you set an jquery event handler to your button?

```
function foo(){
     $(this).hide();
}
$("input[type=button]").click(foo); //set event handler
```

...and remove the onclick attribute:

```
<input type='button' value='Button'>
```

**or** select your button with a class name:

```
function foo(){
     $(this).hide();
}
$(".button").click(foo);
```

...and add a class to your button.

```
<input type='button' class='button' value='Button'>
```

The API for jquery click: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery then you can bind click event directly using class or id

> **Note:** you can use on event for more then one button also see example:

[**WHAT IS THIS**](http://www.sitepoint.com/what-is-this-in-javascript/)

```js
$('.click').click(function(){

 $('h1').html($(this).attr('name'));

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="click" name="one">one</button>
<button class="click" name="two">two</button>
<button class="click" name="three">three</button>
<button class="click" name="four">four</button>
<h1></h1>
```